# ArcGIS arcpy reprojecting raster issue

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I have a raster which I want to reproject from GCS_WGS_1984 to GCS_NorthAmerican_1983. I am using the following code:

```
    try:  
        spatial_ref = arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management("GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision", "", "", "", "", "", "0")
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()

    try:
        arcpy.Project_management(o_dir+int_ras,o_dir+geo_int_ras,spatial_ref)
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

It gives the error:
ERROR 000732: Input Dataset or Feature Class: Dataset does not exist or not supporte

However, the input datasets most defn exist. Is there some issue with how I am reprojecting?

Comment: how do o_dir and int_ras look like ? make sure you have "\\" whan you concatenate your paths.

Comment: As @radouxju suggests, I think these variables may not be set to what you think so don't be afaraid to use print statements to double-check what they are just before you use them in a tool that is throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks guys, but my path is ok. '\\' are in place. However, the error persists. Interestingly, if I bypass the proejection, the next step in the geoprocessing happens just fine i.e. it has no issues with missing datasets.

Comment: Use ProjectRaster, not Project. And I probably wouldn't bother if you're just going WGS84 to NAD83 (lat/lon) if the cell size is more than a meter. Just redefine it using DefineProjection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might as well makes this an answer.

The Project method/tool works with vector data only. To reproject a raster, you need to use the Project Raster tool. That is, the ProjectRaster_management method. The help topic for ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 is [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Project_Raster/00170000007q000000/). Here's the arcpy sample from the help:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.ProjectRaster_management("c:/data/image.tif", "c:/output/reproject.tif",\
                               "World_Mercator.prj", "BILINEAR", "5",\
                               "NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5", "#", "#")
```

It takes a coordinate system, not a spatial reference, and has different parameters (like resampling type and cell size).

On a separate note, is the input raster using WGS 1984, latitude-longitude, or is it actually in a projected coordinate system that's based on WGS 1984? If the former, and the cell size is more than a meter, I wouldn't bother reprojecting the raster but instead use the [Define Projection tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Define_Projection/001700000077000000/) and simply change the coordinate system to NAD 1983.

NAD 1983 and WGS 1984 differ by 1-2 meters only. If your raster's cell size is about that or larger, it's not going to make a difference if you project it and will just cause an unnecessary resampling.

Comment: Thanks mkennedy! The input raster is WGS 1984 (using lat lon) and has a resolution of 0.25 degrees. I defn want to avoid any resampling.